# Gini Coefficient with Infinite Population

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the Gini Coefficient when I have an infinite population $n$ , meaning $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} Gini(n)$.

Defining Gini Coefficient:

\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle Gini={\frac {\displaystyle {\sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\left|u_{i}-u_{j}\right|}}{\displaystyle {2\sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=1}^{n}u_{j}}}}={\frac {\displaystyle {\sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\left|u_{i}-u_{j}\right|}}{\displaystyle {2n\sum _{j=1}^{n}u_{j}}}}={\frac {\displaystyle {\sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\left|u_{i}-u_{j}\right|}}{\displaystyle {2n^{2}{\bar {u}}}}}}
\end{equation}

To my understanding firstly we calculate the $\sum _{j=1}^{\infty}\left|u_{i}-u_{j}\right| = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}S_n$.

From a brief study of mine for infinite series I calculate the following:

\begin{equation}
{
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}S_n = 
\begin{cases}
    0      &, \quad \forall u_i,u_j=0\\
    \infty  &, \quad \forall u_i,u_j \in \mathbb{R}
  \end{cases}
}
\end{equation}

Similarly the $\sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\left|u_{i}-u_{j}\right|$.

Moreover in the denominator:

\begin{equation}
{
\bar{u}=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{f=1}^{n}u_f}{n}
,}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{
\bar{u}= 
\begin{cases}
    0      &, \quad \forall u_i,u_j=0\\
    \infty  &, \quad \forall u_i,u_j \in \mathbb{R}
  \end{cases}
}
\end{equation}

Which results that in neither of the cases the Gini Coefficient with infinite population cannot be defined.

Due to my limited mathematical background may I ask whether my logic and approach is correct or there is another solution that I can try.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No population in practice is infinite. This alone should ensure that the Gini coefficient is always well defined. When you take the limit $n\to\infty$ then $\bar{u}$ (the mean of income/wealth) is not necessarily converging to $\infty$. Same holds for the other term representing the dispersion since that is divided by $n^2$. In [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient#Definition) they also offer a continuous version which corresponds to an infinite population.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! @KurtG., I show the continuous version  but it states that the "the mean of the distribution, and the lower limits of integration may be replaced by zero when all incomes are positive." But doest states Clearly if a population goes to infinity what is the coefficieny values.